# Как считать элементы на странице (величина скидки) для товаров на странице

Tags: java, xpath

Использую xpath для выбора всех скидок на [странице для продуктов](http://store.steampowered.com/tag/ru/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD/#p=0&tab=Discounts):

```
private static final String xpathDescountAll = ".//div[contains(@id,'DiscountsTable')]//div[contains(@class,'discount_pct')]";
```

Нужно считать все скидки на 1-й странице, потом выбрать продукт с максимальной скидкой

```
public void receivingListOfSpecials() {
    final Label listOfSpecials = new Label((By.xpath(xpathDescountAll)));
    List<String> arrayResultList = new ArrayList();
    arrayResultList.add(listOfSpecials.getText());
    System.out.println(arrayResultList);
}
```

такой код берет только первую скидку

спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Дима, возможно Вам больше понравится использование сторонней утилиты [JSoap](https://jsoup.org/)? В результате Ваша задача можно реализовать так (на java 8):

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.nodes.TextNode;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class WebParcer {

    public static final String PAGE_URL = "http://store.steampowered.com/tag/ru/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD/#p=0&tab=Discounts";
    public static final String CLASS_OF_DISCOUNTS_CONTAINER = "DiscountsRows";
    public static final String CLASS_FOR_DISCOUNT_ITEMS = "tab_item";
    public static final String DISCOUNT_PCT_CLASS = "discount_pct";
    public static final String CLASS_FOR_ITEM_NAME = "tab_item_name";

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(PAGE_URL).get();

        Element discountContainer = doc.getElementById(CLASS_OF_DISCOUNTS_CONTAINER);
        Elements newsHeadlines = discountContainer.getElementsByClass(CLASS_FOR_DISCOUNT_ITEMS);
        List<Element> collect = newsHeadlines.stream().sorted((o1, o2) -> {
            Elements discountPctElement1 = o1.getElementsByClass(DISCOUNT_PCT_CLASS);
            Elements discountPctElement2 = o2.getElementsByClass(DISCOUNT_PCT_CLASS);
            TextNode discountNode1 = (TextNode) discountPctElement1.get(0).childNode(0);
            TextNode discountNode2 = (TextNode) discountPctElement2.get(0).childNode(0);

            return discountNode2.getWholeText().compareTo(discountNode1.getWholeText());
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        Element highestDiscountElement = collect.get(0);

        System.out.println(((TextNode) highestDiscountElement.getElementsByClass(DISCOUNT_PCT_CLASS).get(0)
                .childNode(0)).getWholeText());
        System.out.println(((TextNode) highestDiscountElement.getElementsByClass(CLASS_FOR_ITEM_NAME).get(0)
                .childNode(0)).getWholeText());

    }
}
```

Вывод будет таким:

```
-80%
DiRT Rally
```

Надеюсь это поможет.